# Is it possible to limit a Tkinter canvas drawing to a specific frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a python GUI with tkinter that requires drawing lots of circles and lines. I want to limit some of the canvas drawings to a certain part of the window, e.g. the right half. For lines, I can just do the tedious calculation (and have done so) but there's no obvious way to do this for circles because they can be disconnected, so I'm wondering if there's just a simpler solution (possibly a specific keyword) that allows you to limit where canvas can draw? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to show a [mcve] for anyone to help with that. It's going to be very dependent on how your code is layed out.

Comment: You can simply put the canvas in the *"certain part of the window"*.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options that you could try.

1. You could make two separate canvas', one on the right side and one on the left side and only allow the user to draw in the one on the right.
2. Given a center point and a radius, it is possible to calculate if the circle will extend into the left half of the canvas, in which case, you can remove it from the canvas.